# More terminals on cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I want to have one more terminal on `cygwin`. 
Basically I am working on programs related to process. I just want to see all the process when the parent is running.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I did launched the main program in background like this (This program creates a zombie child)

```
./make-zombie.exe &
```

And was able to see the child and parent process...

```
$ ps -e pid,ppid,stat,cmd
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     5052    1832    5052       5224  pty0    27510 16:50:04 /home/process/make-zombie
     1832    4852    1832       4068  pty0    27510 16:49:49 /usr/bin/bash
     3332    5052    5052       3332  pty0    27510 16:50:04 /home/process/make-zombie <defunct>
     4852       1    4852       4852  ?       27510 16:49:49 /usr/bin/mintty
     3656    1832    3656       3080  pty0    27510 16:50:19 /usr/bin/ps
```